# What is Russell Crowe's character in "The Mummy"?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-mummy-2017

Russell Crowe's character is seen with glowing eyes and super human strength in the mummy. But no background information is given.

His evil-ish transformation seems to play no role in the movie plot, any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Russell Crowe is playing [Dr. Henry Jekyll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Jekyll_and_Mr._Hyde_(character)), a well-known (to Anglophones, at least) character from [an 1886 novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Case_of_Dr_Jekyll_and_Mr_Hyde) who invents a potion that regularly transforms him into an evil alter-ego, Mr. Edward Hyde.  This character is one of the "monsters" that Universal Studios is featuring in its ["Dark Universe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Monsters#Dark_Universe) shared-universe movies, of which *The Mummy* is the first.  I don't know why the filmmakers chose to feature him in this movie, but based on the reviews I've read, I doubt they knew either.

Comment: Basically, Russell Crowe is Nick Fury of a different super hero universe.